# Using SQL Query to Retrieve data in COntentProvider Android

Tags: android-sqlite, android-contentprovider

I'm trying to use a Cursor to retrieve data from a database that's structured like this:

```
_id     order_id    item_name   item_quantity
1       1           Biscuits    20
2       1           Sugar       30
3       2           Cars        10
4       2           Tables      30
5       3           Chair       50
6       3           Board       60
7       4           Meat        30
8       4           Fish        40
```

I need to retrieve select order_item, order_id FROM [table_name] WHERE order_id = 1 and I tried this:

```
cursor.moveToFirst();
          StringBuilder res=new StringBuilder();
                while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
                 res.append("\n"+cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("item_name, item_quantity WHERE order_id = 1")));
                    cursor.moveToNext();
                }
                resultView.setText(res);
```

But it gives me error, the error means there's nothing like that in the database

Answer (score 0):

here is your fault :

```
 cursor.getColumnIndex("item_name, item_quantity WHERE order_id = 1")
```

I think you have to change it like this :

```
 cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_NAME_IN_TABLE)
```

Comment: I know it'll retrieve all the item on the column. I don't want everything on the column, all I want is just `order_id    item_name   item_quantity
1           Biscuits    20
1           Sugar       30` I don't want everything in a column, just data where order_id = 1

Comment: if you don't want to retrieve all data, you have to change your select query!
don't use "SELECT * FROM ..." but use "SELECT COLUMN1, COLUMN2, ... FROM ..."